# run function in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, dictionary, lambda, scope

I have a question abount run function.

I totally understand The last 'eachCount()' result, but run function give a bit punch for me.

How does it works?

id_list: ["muzi", "frodo", "apeach", "neo"]

report: ["muzi frodo","apeach frodo","frodo neo","muzi neo","apeach muzi"]

k: 2

Answer: [2, 1, 1, 0]

```
class Solution {
fun solution(id_list: Array<String>, report: Array<String>, k: Int): IntArray =
report.map { it.split(" ") }// [[muzi, frodo], [apeach, frodo], [frodo, neo], [muzi, neo], [apeach, muzi]]

    .groupBy { it[1] }//    {frodo=[[muzi, frodo], [apeach, frodo]], neo=[[frodo, neo], [muzi, neo]], muzi=[[apeach, muzi]]}

    .asSequence()
    .map { it.value.distinct() }//[[[muzi, frodo], [apeach, frodo]], [[frodo, neo], [muzi, neo]], [[apeach, muzi]]]

    .filter { it.size >= k }//  [[[muzi, frodo], [apeach, frodo]], [[frodo, neo], [muzi, neo]]]

    .flatten()//    [[muzi, frodo], [apeach, frodo], [frodo, neo], [muzi, neo]]

    .map { it[0] }//[muzi, apeach, frodo, muzi]

    .groupingBy { it }
    .eachCount()//  {muzi=2, apeach=1, frodo=1} -> run function's reciver object??
    .run { id_list.map { getOrDefault(it, 0)}.toIntArray() } -> I don`t know how it works.
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`thing.run` puts you inside the scope of `thing`, as if you're running code inside its class, and inside the function block, `this` is `thing`. Usually that's for convenience, so you don't have to keep referring to the object explicitly:

```
// also useful for null-checking stuff before you try to do things with it!
thing?.run {
    doThing()
    println(someProperty)
}
```

`let` is similar, but instead of the object you're calling it on becoming a *receiver* (`this` in the function), it's passed in as a *parameter* instead:

```
thing?.let {
    // now you have to explicitly refer to the parameter
    it.doThing()
    println(it.someProperty)
}
```

There are similar pairs of receiver/parameter scope functions that do similar things, like `apply/also`. Which one you pick depends on what makes most sense. If you're calling things with the object as a parameter, it might feel more correct to call `doThing(it)` (or a renamed parameter that reads better!) than `doThing(this)`

---

The important thing in your bit of code is that the last line uses `run` **and** `let`. That allows it to refer to *two different objects* at that stage in the chain - the result of all the stuff that happened before (which has `run` called on it, so it becomes the receiver, `this`) and the current item in the `map` call, `it`.

You're basically calling all that stuff and producing a `Map`. Then you call `run`, which is going to transform that `Map` into another value, and gives you access to the `Map` through `this`. Then you produce a value to output by calling `map` on your `id_list` and doing a lookup on your `Map`, through `this.getOrDefault` (which you can shorten to just `getOrDefault`).

It's basically the equivalent to this:

```
val myMap = // big chain of operations
val lookup = id_list.map { myMap.getOrDefault(it, 0) }.toIntArray()
return lookup
```

only `run` works as part of that big chain, transforming one value to another without declaring intermediate variables.

Btw you *could* use `let` if you wanted, so there are two parameters involved - one from the `let` function, one from the `map` function:

```
// giving it a name because you can't have two things called 'it'
.let { myMap -> id_list.map { myMap.getOrDefault(it, 0)}.toIntArray() }
```

but that's probably not an improvement, right? You can do it if you prefer it though, or want to be more explicit! (Being able to name the parameters can be a great way to document exactly what's happening - it might not be clear what the thing you're calling `run` or `let` on actually *is*, and a name can help)

Answer (score 0):

The last line is equivalent to

```
.run { id_list.map { this.getOrDefault(it, 0) }.toIntArray() }
```

where `this` is the map returned by `.eachCount()` on the previous line and `it` is each element of `id_list`.